# Shortest path between nodes across multiple matrices

Tags: python-2.7, graph-algorithm, shortest-path

Say I have a matrix of train stations per line. The rows and columns represent the stations present in that train line.  Is there a way to find the shortest path among stations including those that uses transfer between train lines? I can't put them all in one graph because some "edges" have different value (e.g. if the parameter is cost, taking the cheaper line will cost differently than taking the other train route).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Dijkstra's algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

It's used all over from video games [(A*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) to [dynamic routing protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Shortest_Path_First#Overview).

A pretty good introduction to A*: http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/AStarComparison.html

Comment: Thank you for your fast comment! Will it work even on multiple graphs?

Comment: Ah, my bad. I was picturing a table to represent the vertices and edges. I almost forgot that if I used a graph instead, there can be two edges between two vertices. Anyway, thank you for your time and the links! I'll start with them in choosing which algorithm I'll use.